# Responsive svg content

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to make the cut out inside the svg respect the same grid as the external content (so it can align with the button outside). The objective is to make the bar support removing or adding buttons as needed.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/lkjimy/pen/dyYgeQO)

(That is the code, broken on the stackoverflow editor. Can't import bootstrap stylesheet for some reason. check the codepen above)

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, orange, teal, grey);
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bar .content .btn {
  height: 59px;
  width: 59px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.bar .content .btn.active {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.bar svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!--<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->

<div class="bar">
  <div class="container content" id="html">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="btn">BTN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="btn">BTN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="btn">BTN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="btn active">BTN</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <svg>
    <mask id="myMask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <circle cx="85%" cy="10" r="36" fill="black" />
    </mask>

    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="16" width="100%" height="120%" fill="white" mask="url(#myMask)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:** It needs to be a cut out of the bar, not a trick with colored borders, it was designed to be a transparent space in the shape of a circle. Added colored background to body. Codepen also updated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with SVG? The same effect could be created in CSS very easily and with much less chance of breaking in different browsers etc.

Comment: In my reseach I found that this is the most widely compatible way, [as you can see in this aticle](https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/). Using the css clip, wouldn't help me, considering it cuts out the content outside the shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exact same effect using just CSS and flexbox. If you plan on using a shape divider instead of a flat bar there are ways you can shape the bar using purely CSS of if you want to use SVG then simply swap out the the bar CSS below with an SVG, and it should effect the button locations.

You can learn more about how to use flexbox here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And a guide on how to use shape dividers https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/

```css
body {
  background: #1a7b6c;
  height:100vh;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background:#fff;
}

.bar .row {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bar .btn {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background: white;
  text-align:center;
}

.bar .btn.active {
  margin-top: -20px;
  border:#1a7b6c 10px solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="btn">BTN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="btn">BTN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="btn active">BTN</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I considered using the border color trick, but it was designed to be transparent, there will be content scrolling behind it. I updated the bg color to make it more obvious.

Comment: Well then the simplest way to achieve that again is with CSS and using a masking trick with transparency. You can use the CSS to effectively cut holes in the background image and place then as part of the button removing the need for them to be perfectly aligned to a static background mask and the heaache of keeping them aligned https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/